# How to control rate limiting for free premium twitter api

Tags: python, twitter, rate-limiting

I'm using Python 3.7 with [searchtweets](https://github.com/twitterdev/search-tweets-python) to scrape some basic data from the twitter api, and i want to be able to suspend process when the rate limit has been hit. I currently only have access to the free packages (sandbox and the limited premium). I was able to do this with tweepy and the sandbox package, which doesn't allow historical searches.

I have progressed to try to get more data with historical tweets using [searchtweets](https://github.com/twitterdev/search-tweets-python), but this does not seem to have any access to the rate_limit_status that was available in the sandbox package ([open issue](https://github.com/twitterdev/search-tweets-python/issues/40)).

I have tried the suggestion in [the response](https://github.com/igorbrigadir/search-tweets-python/blob/rate-limits/searchtweets/result_stream.py#L111-L113) to the issue, but it still returns to [429 error code](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/response-codes)

Does anyone know how to access the rate_limit_status in [searchtweets](https://github.com/twitterdev/search-tweets-python) or is there any other way to determine how many request i have remaining?